# Button & Title Design on Login Page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a simple login page in react native and am facing some confusions in styling. How can I make the text on the button in the center?

How can I take the INSTARIDE text upwards and not so close to the username field. Code could be run on Expo Snack.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, Button, Text, Container, Header, Content, TextInput, Form, Item, View, Label, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }

  onLogin() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;

    Alert.alert('Credentials', `${username} + ${password}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
          My App
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.username}
          onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
          placeholder={'Username'}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
          placeholder={'Password'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          style={styles.input}
        />

        <Button rounded success
          title={'Login!'}
          style={styles.input}
          color = '#65c756'
          onPress={this.onLogin.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#1b1c1c',
  },
  input: {
    width: 200,
    height: 33,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: @Rob I have posted the same code as in the picture. The screenshot was just for the visual representation of the output.

Comment: Then I can delete the picture for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this below code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, Button, Text, TextInput, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }
  onLogin() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    Alert.alert('Credentials', `${username} + ${password}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>My App</Text>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.username}
          onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
          placeholder={'Username'}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
          placeholder={'Password'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
          <Button
            rounded
            success
            title={'Login!'}
            color="#65c756"
            onPress={this.onLogin.bind(this)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    width: '90%',
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    width: '90%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginBottom: 30, 
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

Change this according to your requirement. Feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

Create custom button by text and touchable opacity

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'#65c756',paddingVertical:5,paddingHorizontal: 30,borderRadius:6}} onPress={this.onLogin.bind(this)}>
        <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Login!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

for text close to input just add some padding or margin b/w them

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can move the text on the button to it's center? I tried alignItems but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To center the button, try adding `text-align: center;` to the `style` prop in `<Text style={{color:'white'}}>Login!</Text>`